# How do I display any number of input text field on a modal depending on number of element in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-bootstrap, input-field

Hello i'm new to ReactJS and Javascript. How do I display any number of textbox (input field, text input) on a modal, depending on the number of words that are in a sentence?

For example because there a 5 words in "Hope you are doing great", the number of input textfields in the modal should be 5.

I'm currently doing this:

```
  const [inputFields, setInputField] = useState([
    {word: ''},{word: ''},{word: ''},{word: ''},{word: ''}
])
```

and

```
<InputGroup className="mb-3">
            {inputFields.map((inputField, index) => (
              
                <Form key={index}>
                    <Form.Control label="word" name="word" value={inputField.word} />
  
                </Form>

            ))} 
           
        </InputGroup>
```

but its manual and i'd love to make it work dynamically on it's own.

I count the number of words as per usual:

```
 const handleShow = (poem) => {
  var lyric = poem.lyrics;
  var words_array = lyric.split(' ')
  var words_num = words_array.length
  console.log(words_num)
  setShow(true)
};
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export default function DynamicInputs({poem}){
   const [inputFields, setInputField] = useState([])


   useEffect(() => {
     setInputField(poem.lyrics.split(' ').map(word => ({word})))     
   }, [poem])

   return (
     <>
       {
        inputFields.map((field, index) => (
          <input type="text" key={index}/>
        )) 
       }
     </>
   )

}
```

Comment: Since you are splitting the sentence, create an object for each word and update your state, there is no need to do it manually. I'm editing the snippet